# socket.io-client ошибка компиляции после обновления до typescript 2.9.2

Tags: typescript, socket.io

Есть небольшое приложение на angular 6.0.7 / typescript 2.7.2.
Подключал socket.io-client так:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

все работало.
 
Вот решил сделать красиво и обновился до angular 6.1.0 / typescript 2.9.2.
Сборка фейлится, редактор в строчке с подключением библиотеки выдает следующую подсказку: Импорт стиля пространства имен не может быть вызван или создан и приведет к сбою во время выполнения.
Консоль на строчку

```
private socket = io();
```

выдает ошибку:
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ connect(uri: string, opts?: ConnectOpts): Socket; connect(opts?: ConnectOpts): Socket; protocol...' has no compatible call signatures.
 
Что посоветуете сделать?

Comment: Удалил из зависимостей @types/socket.io-client - заработало. Но, блин, это же не круто(

Comment: у вас где-то в `tsconfig.json` или `tsconfig.app.json` есть свойство `esModuleInterop: true`?

Comment: в tsconfig.json есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это никак не связано с версией `typescript`. Можете вернуть обратно определения `@types/socket.io-client`. Это ошибка может возникать только с параметром `esModuleInterop: true`. Когда вы ставите `esModuleInterop: true` - это говорит компилятору обернуть `require('any-module')` в сгенерированную функцию `__importStar`, которая проверяет является ли модуль `es6` или `commonjs`. Этот параметр не нужно использовать в проектах `angular`, он был добавлен командой Microsoft (из-за большого кол-во `issues` разработчиков на `React`) исключительно в тех целях, чтобы, например `import * as React from 'react` можно было заменить на `import React from 'react'`, при этом компилятор не ругался.

Comment: По Вашей наводке начал копать документацию. Добавил в tsconfig.app.json правило "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true - жаработало.